# How to Set "audit-enabled":false in MarkLogic at the time of deployment

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

How can I set `"audit-enabled":false` in MarkLogic at the time of deployment
in the groups.json file?

Comment: Are you using ml-gradle? or another method?

Comment: i am using ml-gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom task that makes a call to [https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/groups/[id-or-name]/properties](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/groups/%5Bid-or-name%5D/properties) to modify the audit-enabled property, along with any other properties of the group that you want. See https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Writing-your-own-task for examples on how to write a custom task.